# How do I match link text that is wrapped in an html tag using xpath?

Tags: html, xpath, capybara

I have this link:

```
<a href="/stores/non-consequatur-totam/products/search?term=yellow">
    Search all categories in 
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">non consequatur totam's</span> 
    store for “yellow”
</a>
```

I am trying to match it using xpath, but I can only match the portion before the span, using contains and text().  I am using capybara.

```
page.all(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(), 'Search all categories in')]").first
=> #<Capybara::Element tag="a" path="/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/p[2]/a[1]">
page.all(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(), 'store for')]").first
=> nil
```

How do I match the actual text, like jQuery would? I need to ignore the inner html tags. I would really like to be able to match the portion in the span too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* what you are looking for is the *string value* of an element. The string value of an element node is just the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes.

Using the expression `string(//a)` on almost (to avoid any unrelated problem with single or double quotes in the text content) the HTML snippet you have shown:

```
<a href="/stores/non-consequatur-totam/products/search?term=yellow">
    Search all categories in 
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">non consequatur totams</span> 
    store for yellow
</a>
```

yields

```
[EMPTY OUTPUT LINE]
Search all categories in
non consequatur totams
store for yellow
[EMPTY OUTPUT LINE]
```

and that's all the text inside the `a` element. Now, to match an `a` element by its text content, test for `string()` in a predicate:

```
//a[normalize-space(string(.)) = 'Search all categories in non consequatur totams store for yellow']
```

Applied to the slightly modified input again, this will return the link element.

`normalize-space()` is necessary because the textual content includes newline characters and those are hard to include in an XPath expression.

---

To respond to a comment of yours and give another example of this:

> I would really like to be able to use a single contains, assuming I had `<a>a b <span>c</span d</div>` I would like to look for `a b c`

I assume you mean searching

```
<a>a b <span>c</span> d</a>
```

and look for `a b c d`? Using the method explained above, use

```
//a[normalize-space(string(.)) = 'a b c d']
```

Comment: No, I meant I wanted to search for a b c, just like I said. I will give this a shot and I think I can use it combined with `contains`. I go another route already, but this is still good information to have. If it works, I will be sure to accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: `"//a[contains(normalize-space(string(.)), 'Search all categories in #{store.name}')]"` worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @Brandon You are welcome - glad you got it to work. No need for me to edit the answer, you're good at combining the facts anyway.